# When were the 'last' pagans in northern Europe converted to christianity?

Tags: europe, christianity, reformation

I've always found it interesting that the Reformation 'began' in Norther Europe.  It strikes me that most of the various Christian sects seemed to form within different ethnic groups.  So, I'm wondering how long Catholicism lasted in northern Europe before being official rejected.

Comment: Interesting question, perhaps even deeper than you realize - lousy title for it. I think you are trying a bit too hard for title **impact**.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your question, since the title seem to contain a completely different question than the body. Perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: @LennartRegebro I apologize for any confusion.  My headline question is really the question I want answered.  The information below is just for context.  I consider 1517 the beginning of the official rejection Catholicism.   All I'm missing is the 'end' of Paganism to see how long Catholicism lasted in norther Europe.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens How is the question deeper?  I find the subject of long lasting ethnic differences in europe fascinating. It's really interesting that differences between Celts and Germanic peoples lasted (continue to last?) so long.

Comment: @dwstein But you see "how long Catholicism lasted in northern Europe" is a question with absolutely zero connection to the headline. So you are still confused on what you want to answer.

Comment: Are you talking about paganism or Protestantism?  The Reformation has nothing to do with paganism.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - I understand protestantism is not paganism.  I'm suggesting that many ethnic groups have adopted their own form of christianity.  History is typically taught suggesting the protestant reformation took place based on ideological differences.  In fact, I think, it took place largely along ethnic lines.

Comment: Your headline speaks of converting pagans (i.e. non-Christians in a Christian context) to Christianity. Your question text speaks of the reformation, which changed Catholic areas into protestant ones. Two completely different things (unless you consider Catholicism to be a pagan religion of course).

Comment: @dwstein - A good question about the intersection of religious sects and ethnic identities is probably waiting to be asked about. The question in your title is also IMHO a good question. However, I don't really see how they are the same question. I've tried to edit this question to be consistent. If you want to ask a larger question about religion and ethnicity, I'd encourage you to do it as a separate question, if you can find a way to express it well.

Comment: @T.E.D. Maybe the combination of the title and the description implies that Catholicism is Pagan. I know quite a few Baptist who would ascribe to that.

Comment: Based on the last edit from the OP, I think @MarioElocio may be onto something. dwstein, this is *not* the place to push your **own personal taxonomy** of religions. We must all understand each other here to get useful answers. [Pagan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagan_religions#History) generally refers to pre-Catholic religions in Europe, while "Protestant" refers to post-Catholic (post-Martin Luther) Christian religions. Its very unfair to our posters to leave this question open with such confusing terminology, so I'm closing it until you can fix this issue. Give a shout when done.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I think the question is interesting; perhaps the title should be changed to something like "Timeline and causes of Catholicism setback in Northern Europe".

Comment: @Michael - I agree about promise in this question (and at least 9 votes on answers back you up). However, an attempt to make the verbiage in this question and its title consistent (and consistent with the question no less than two posters thought was being asked) has been rolled back by the author. So if that's the proper solution, the author (the only person who can accept answers) should probably be the one to make that edit. You could try it yourself, and if the OQ posts a comment agreeing with the edit it would probably be OK to reopen too.

Answer (score 6):

The last major pagan group in Europe was the Sami in northern Scandinavia.

Although missionaries traveled north and churches were built aready in the 16th-17th century, the sami were predominantly pagan until forced christianization that started in the 18th century. (1720 in Norway, late 18th century in Sweden).

Although officially Christian since the 18th century, the Sami didn't really take to christianity until the 19th century with Lars Levi Laestadius' revival movement.

[Further reading.](http://www.utexas.edu/courses/sami/diehtu/siida/christian/decline.htm)

Comment: Figured it would probably be the Sami (if indeed they have converted). However, also voting up Mario's answer, because the Sami never really had an organized state that participated meaningfully in European politics.

Answer (score 5):

An answer to the question in your title would be the 14th/15th century and relate to the Duchy of Lithuania. For an account of the causes see eg. *W Urban: The Conversion of Lithuania* (**[1987](http://www.lituanus.org/1987/87_4_03.htm)**).

EDIT:

It could be that the question is really about *the end of Catholicism is Northern Europe*. If so my answer is this:

- Catholicism was *not* rejected all over Northern Europe. Lithuania is in Northern Europe, and it is still a very Catholic country.
  .

Comment: Seems like you are a century or three off, though myself I originally expected this to be the correct answer.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Yes and no. The conversion in Lithuania would be the last one in Europe for a *polity*, the conversion of the Sami (or the Nenets in Russia) the last for an ethnic group.

Comment: I also expected this answer to be correct. I had no idea about the Sami. Still, both answers make it pretty clear that "the last pagans" has very little to do with how long catholicism lasted.